# Difference in arrayList size

Tags: java

If I have an ArrayList of Objects in Java, is the underlying implementation really just an array of object references? I'm creating this method:

```
//method returns all combinations of Objects
public ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getAllCombinations(ArrayList<Object> allObjects){

}
```

As I started thinking about the problem, I wondered if I could just return an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` where the ints were the position in allObjects (essentially thinking this would use drastically less memory). But then I started thinking that each value of the array implementation just points to the memory location of the objects in the  and that the array wasn't creating new objects for each ArrayList I was creating (which would definitely use more memory). So in reality, it would use about the same memory if I just implement the method I mentioned above, right?

I think I need to understand Java's memory allocation a little bit better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an array or an arraylist only contains references to objects, not the objects themselves. So each item in your array uses 4 bytes of memory (on a 32 bit machine), regardless of the size of the underlying objects.

So keep it simple and return whatever makes sense.

Comment: While I see the point that you're making, it is at least slightly specious to maintain that each element uses only 4 bytes.  While it's true that the reference is only that large, this overlooks the fact that space must be allocated from the heap for each of the objects.

Comment: @scottb Yes obviously - the op seems to be concerned that putting objects in an arraylist will double the size they use. I tried to explain that even a large object will add 4 bytes of "memory usage" when put in a list. (That is a simplification as the underlying array is not resized at each addition)

Comment: @scottb could you explain what you mean about the allocation from the heap for each object?

Comment: @sunrize920 I think he just meant that the object will use more than 4 bytes, it is only the reference stored in the list/array which uses 4 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You got that right: The elements of your `ArrayList` will only *point* to the objects (except if you copy them explicitly). So both implementations will use about the same memory as you say.

This is by the way something important to consider, if you want to alter the state of your objects as they will also seem altered in the old array where they originated from.